# Confusion about the use of the phrase "a por"

Tags: preposiciones

This is another chapter in my attempt to grasp Spanish prepositions, probably a hopeless quest.

In the on-line coverage of the Vuelta a España 2022 at one point they wrote

> Cambio de ritmo de Marc Soler (UAE Team Emirates), que se lanza a por Lawson Craddock (Team BikeExchange-Jayco).

I know what it means: MS upped his pace to chase after LC. But what is the usage of *a por* here?

Comment: Yes, to go for, he went **for** him. The answer below explains it well just not sure about it never being used in SA.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> El uso de la secuencia de preposiciones a por tras verbos que indican movimiento, como ir, venir, volver, salir, etc., con el sentido de ‘en busca de’, es hoy normal en el español de España, donde es corriente decir *Ve a por agua, Salgo a por el pan, Volvió a por el paraguas*. En el español de América, en cambio, este uso se percibe como anómalo y sigue siendo general allí el empleo exclusivo, en estos casos, de la preposición por: Ve por agua, Salgo por el pan, Volvió por el paraguas.

- The use of the sequence of prepositions `a por` after verbs that indicate movement, such as to go, to come, to return, to leave, etc., with the meaning of 'in search of', is today normal in the **Spanish of Spain**, where it is common to say *Ve a por agua, Salgo a por el pan, Volvió a por el paraguas*. In **American Spanish**, on the other hand, this use is perceived as anomalous, and generally continues to be the exclusive use, in these cases, of the preposition `por`: *Ve por agua, Salgo por el pan, Volvió por el paraguas*.

<sub>*Source and more info: [RAE](https://www.rae.es/espanol-al-dia/ir-por-agua-o-ir-por-agua#:%7E:text=El%20uso%20de%20la%20secuencia,Volvi%C3%B3%20a%20por%20el%20paraguas.)*</sub>

Comment: Please: South American Spanish. Versus: Iberian Spanish. I am just not sure that in SA they don't use it. I can't say. I hear it all the time, anyway, to mean for.

Comment: I only heard it in Spain, never in SA or CA.

Answer (score 3):

**Español/English Version**

---

**ESPAÑOL**

Resumen de contenidos

---

Existe un estudio interesante y más o menos amplio de Jairo Javier García Sánchez de la Universidad de Alcalá titulado, " **A por, ¿una expresión censurable?** ".

https://cvc.cervantes.es/literatura/aih/pdf/14/aih_14_1_029.pdf

El trabajo cuenta un poco la historia y trayectoria que va desde el "**por**" al "**a por**", expresión está "**a por**", que parece se desarrolló en la España del S. XIX.

Primero fue su censura, llevada a cabo desde la propia Real Academia Española en la edición de 1874, para luego encontrar la justificación paulatina realizada por variedad de lingüistas y autores, que veían en  **"a por**" una expresión propia de español de España, y que hoy en día sí está aceptada por la Academia de la Lengua.

En el análisis podemos encontrar notas interesantes que hacen referencia a otros estudios realizados por otros autores foráneos como es el caso de la nota;

- 15 Cf Peggy D. Hart «The use of the preposition <**por**> when it means <**to fetch**»>, Hispania
  LVI, 1973, p. 646.

> la razón que se ha esgrimido en favor de la combinación de las dos
> preposiciones. Quizás la más recurrente es la que se basa en que "**a
> por**" permite deshacer ambigüedades.
>
> • De esta manera, «**voy a por mi hijo**» sólo puede significar "voy a
> buscar a mi hijo" frente a «voy por mi hijo», que resultaría ambiguo
> ("voy a buscar a mi hijo", "Voy en lugar de mi hijo", "voy porque mi
> hijo me lo ha pedido", etc).
>
> • Hart explicaba la **anfibología** con la traducción al inglés de «Yo
> vine por ti» = <I came because of you /to pick you up /in your stead.
>
> • Vemos así que la preposición "**por**" posee el significado de <(**ir**) **a**
> **buscar** entre otros muchos, mientras que "**a por**" sólo tiene ése.

es decir, **un uso más específico**

> ...a Julio Casares defendía la expresión "**a por**" señalando la función
> que desempeña para evitar anfibologías. El ejemplo que pone... "Sube
> **por** la escalera".../(frente)/... "Sube **a por** la escalera" no admite
> anfibología

(**Anfibología** Doble sentido de una palabra o frase que puede provocar dudas e interpretaciones erróneas).

el uso es más específico, y lo que se entiende es que se "**Sube para coger una de esas escaleras móviles o plegables**".

> **Nuestra hipótesis** (Jairo Javier García Sánchez)
>
> Nadie ha reparado, que nosotros sepamos, en que «**ir a por** (algo o
> alguien)» **es en realidad una estructura elíptica** en la que se ha
> eliminado el complemento circunstancial de lugar que rige la
> preposición "**a**" y que iría justo delante de la otra preposición "**por**".

---

*Cambio de ritmo de Marc Soler, que se lanza* "**a por**" *Lawson Craddock*.

Cabe señalar en estas oraciones, " *...que se lanza* **a por**", como en otras parecidas, dos aspectos que son complementarios.

- 1. Vendría a significar una forma más específica de "ir en busca de", figurativamente atrapar, pillar a alguien e implícitamente superarlo o neutralizarlo, en esta ocasión a Lawson Craddock del equipo Jayco.
- 2. Este tipo de expresiones "**a por**" poseerían en realidad una **estructura elíptica** (elíptica, oraciones en las que se omite o se da por entendido algún elemento de las mismas), en donde se sobrentiende el verbo "ir", Marc Soler, que se lanza* "**a (ir) por**" *Lawson.

Algunos son ejemplos del trabajo.

Ir a por vino - Ir **a** (la tienda) **por** vino.

Ir a por agua - tuvo su origen en una elipsis del tipo - Ir **a** (la fuente) **por** agua.

¡A por la victoria! - ¡Vamos **a** (ir) **por** la victoria!

¡A por todas! - ¡Vamos **a** (ir) **por** todas!

> Enunciados como «El Mallorca viaja a Madrid **a por** la victoria», es
> decir, «**ir a** alguna parte **a por** algo» (a - a por), se pueden analizar
> perfectamente desde nuestra hipótesis como casos saturados,
> posteriores a las primeras formaciones de **a por** debidas a elipsis. **"A**
> **por"** **se ha convertido ya en una estructura unitaria, no desglosable**.

---

**Real Academia Española**

> No hay razones lingüísticas para condenar el uso de a por, tan
> legítimo como el de otras combinaciones de preposiciones nunca
> censuradas. La secuencia **a por** (documentada ya en textos españoles de
> los siglos XVI y XVII) se explica por el **cruce** de las estructuras **ir a**
> **un lugar** (complemento de dirección) **e ir por algo o alguien** (‘en busca
> de’), ya que en esta última está también presente la idea de
> ‘movimiento hacia’. Por otra parte, el uso de ambas preposiciones,
> frente al empleo aislado de **por**, resuelve en muchos casos problemas de
> ambigüedad.

https://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/a_por

---

**English**

Summary

---

There is an interesting and more or less extensive study by Jairo Javier García Sánchez from the University of Alcalá entitled, **"A por, ¿una expresión censurable?"**

https://cvc.cervantes.es/literatura/aih/pdf/14/aih_14_1_029.pdf

In it he tells a little about the history and trajectory of the "**por**" to the "**a por**", which seems to have developed in Spain in the 19th century. First its censorship from the Royal Spanish Academy, in the 1874 edition and then the justification of the expression **"a por**", for a few years by some linguists and other authors. In it we can find interesting notes that refer to other studies carried out by other foreign authors, as is the case of the note;

- 15 Cf Peggy D. Hart «The use of the preposition <**por**> when it means <**to fetch**»>, Hispania
  LVI, 1973, p. 646.

> the reason that has been given in favor of the combination of the two
> prepositions. Perhaps the most recurrent is the one based on the fact that "**a
> por**" allows to undo ambiguities.
>
> • In this way, «**voy a por mi hijo / I'm going for my son**» can only mean "voy a
> buscar a mi hijo" / I'm going to
> to look for my son > versus "voy **por** mi hijo", which would be ambiguous,
> ( "voy a buscar a mi hijo" / I am going to look for my son, < "Voy en lugar de mi hijo" / I am going instead of my son, < "voy porque mi hijo me lo ha pedido" / I am going because my
> son asked me, etc.)
>
> • Hart explained **amphibology** with the English translation of «
> I came for you» = I came because of you /to pick you up /in your stead.
>
> • We thus see that the preposition "**por**" has the meaning of <(**ir**) **a**
> **buscar** among many others, while "**a por**" only has that one.

i.e. **a more specific use**

> ...Julio Casares defended the expression "**a por**" pointing out the function
> that he performs to avoid amphibologies. The example that sets... " "Sube **por** la escalera" Go up
> up the ladder".../(front)/... "Sube **a por** la escalera",(the expression) does not support
> amphiboly

(**Amphibology** Double meaning of a word or phrase that can cause doubts and erroneous interpretations).

the use is more specific, "Sube a por la escalera" and it is understood that "**Go up to get one of those mobile or folding ladders**".

> **Our hypothesis** (Jairo Javier García Sánchez)
>
> No one has noticed, to our knowledge, that «**ir a por** (something or
> someone)» **is actually an elliptical structure** in which
> eliminated the circumstantial complement of place that governs the
> preposition "**a**" and that it would go right before the other preposition "**por**".

---

*Cambio de ritmo de Marc Soler, que se lanza* "**a por**" *Lawson Craddock*.

It should be noted in these sentences, "*...que se lanza* **a por**", as in other similar ones, two aspects that are complementary.

- 1. In this case "**a por**", it would mean a more specific way of "going after", figuratively catching, catching someone, and implicitly overpowering or neutralizing them, this time Lawson Craddock of Team Jayco.
- 2. This type of expressions "**a por**" would actually have an **elliptical structure/estructura elíptica** (elliptical, sentences in which some element of them is omitted or taken for granted), where it is understood the verb "ir", Marc Soler, que se lanza* "**a (ir) por**" *Lawson.

Some are examples of work.

Go for water / Ir **a por** agua - had its origin in an ellipsis of the type - Ir **a** (la fuente) **por** agua.

Ir **a por** vino - Ir **a** (la tienda) **por** vino.

¡**A por** la victoria! - ¡Vamos **a** (ir) **por** la victoria!

¡**A por** todas! - ¡Vamos **a** (ir) **por** todas!

> Statements such as «Mallorca viaja a Madrid **a por** la victoria», is
> say, "**ir a** somewhere **a por** something" (a - a por), they can be parsed
> perfectly from our hypothesis as saturated cases,
> after the first formations of **a por** due to ellipses. **"A**
> **por"** **has already become a unitary structure, not breakable**.

---

**Real Academia Española**

> There are no linguistic reasons to condemn the use of **a por**, so
> legitimate like that of other combinations of prepositions never
> censored. The sequence **a por** (already documented in Spanish texts of
> the 16th and 17th centuries) is explained by the **crossing** of the structures **ir a un lugar/go to**
> **a place** (address complement) **and e ir por algo o alguien / go for something or someone** (‘looking for /
> (‘en busca de’), since in the latter the idea of
> ‘movement towards’. On the other hand, the use of both prepositions,
> compared to the isolated use of **por**, it solves in many cases problems of
> ambiguity.

Comment: I remember being taught in school that *a por* was wrong. Eventually, usage changes linguistic paradigms.